# Is it possible to load an Image in a unity canvas from an URL?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an app that tries to display an Image from an URL (the url works), I googled and found this code:

```cs
public void Start()
    {

        StartCoroutine(GetRequest(URL + code + "&position=" + position)); //the parameters are to get to the correct image in the database
    }
    IEnumerator GetRequest(string url)
    {
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        else
            textureDisplayer.texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;
    }
```

But it marks an error in the "textureDisplayer.texture" portion, and I have that object as an Image, and when I chage it to MainTexture, it says that the whole line has an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the error please

Comment: Thing is, it doesn't show the error. It just mark the line with a red underline...it says that Image doesn't have a definition for texture

Comment: OK, so ```textureDisplayer``` is an object in your scene? Also, what is ```MainTexture```? You're saying you want to "change **it** to MainTexture", but I'm not really sure what you are trying to change.

Answer (score 2):

You say your `textureDisplayer` is an [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html). It has no property `texture`.

Usually what you assign is the [`Image.sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image-sprite.html) so what you want to do would be creating a [`Sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.html) using [`Sprite.Create`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) and use that one instead.

```
IEnumerator GetRequest(string url)
{
    UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url);
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
    if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning(request.error);
        yield break;
    }
    
    var texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
    var sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f);
    textureDisplayer.sprite = sprite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `textureDisplayer` (whatever this was) was not a Material, hence the error "doesn't have a definition for texture" was being displayed.

Say that you have a game object named **mycube**, you can set the material into `textureDisplayer` with the following script:

```cs
        GameObject mygameobject = GameObject.Find("mycube");
        Material textureDisplayer = mygameobject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
```

Then you can access `mainTexture` with the following script:

```cs
textureDisplayer.mainTexture
```